# Angular call function in ng-click defined in object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Got a question about Angularjs and it's ng-repeat/ng-click workings.

So on this system that I'm working on there is a lot of code re-used for datatables, and I'm trying to make a generic template/service to remedy this. Now I'm running into a problem where we have multiple buttons with their own function calls on being clicked.

I've so far got this setup:
My column object defined as so:

```js
var columns = [
        {
            identifier: "id",
            type: "text"
        },
        {
            identifier: "type",
            type: "text"
        },
        {
            identifier: "label",
            type: "text"
        },
        {
            identifier: "actions",
            type: "button",
            multi: true,
            content: [
                {
                    icon: "fa-globe",
                    events: {
                        click: $scope.openMapModal
                    }
                },
                {
                    icon: "fa-list",
                    events: {
                        click: $scope.openGroupModal
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

And my HTML as following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in table.data" ng-model-instant>
    <td ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-if="column.type === 'text'">
        {{TableService.getByString(row, column.identifier)}}
    </td>

    <td ng-repeat="column in table.columns" ng-if="column.type === 'button' && column.multi">
        <a ng-repeat="button in column.content" class="btn fa {{button.icon}}" ng-click="button.events.click(row)"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Just for completeness, my TableService.getByString and a small table data set:
(note that columns defined above is set by a function into the table object, and I did not include it in the object).

```js
var table = {
    data: [
        {
            id: 0,
            label: "foo",
            type: "bar"
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            label: "one",
            type: "bar"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            label: "foo",
            type: "two"
        }
    ]
}

function getKeyObj(obj, key) {
    var retVal = {
        "key": key,
        "obj": obj
    };

    if (retVal.key.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        var keyParts = retVal.key.split('.');
        retVal.key = keyParts.pop();
        while (keyParts.length && (obj = obj[keyParts.shift()])) ;
        retVal.obj = obj;
    }

    return retVal;
}

function getByString(obj, key) {
    var ret = getKeyObj(obj, key);
    return ret.obj[ret.key];
}
```

Now the problem that I'm encountering is that my functions are not being called in my ng-click's whenever I click on the buttons.

I've also tried it with settings the function as a string in my column object, but it didn't work either.

Am I going in the right direction with this or do I need to rethink my generalization, and ifso, what alternative is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure $scope.openMapModal is defined at the time you define the columns array? Could it be that you are assigning undefined to the click property instead of a reference to the function?

Comment: Oh! I haven't thought about that! This was exactly the case. Thank you!